# How to translate "Wise words about life" into latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

As it is said on title, how to translate "Wise words about life" into latin?

Edit:
Answer to Nickimite

Some examples about wise words as I mean:

nanos gigantum humeris insidentes

nulius in verba

cogito ergo sum ... etc

I imagined it like a book's title which includes quotes from medieval age scientists.

Comment: Can you give some more detail? Who might be saying this? Who might be receiving these words? Can you give some examples in English of what some "wise words" might be? In what sense do you mean life? The way one should live their life? These are just some examples.

Comment: Added on the body thank you for your question

Comment: @Nabla: If "wise words" is synonymous with advice then verb "moneo" = to warn"; "to give advice"; de (pronoun taking the ablative case) = "concerning"; "vita" = "life" and looks the same in the ablative case giving "de vita monere" = "to give advice about life".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very straightforward rendering would be:

> *Sententiae* (or *aphorismi*) sapientes de vivendo

I'm reminded of the [collection of pithy Latin quotes](http://www.voxlatina.uni-saarland.de/isal.htm) by Andreas Fritsch, one of the most prominent recent proponents of living Latin, which is titled: *Index sententiarum ac locutionum*. It does not quite fit your request, though: He makes no promise that the quotes are particularly wise ;-)

Comment: Dear Sebastian Koppehel thank you for your time.